# require.js load the same files, do not depending what I put to main.js

Tags: angularjs, requirejs

I have main.js file which looks like this

```
require.config({
paths: {
    'angular': '../../dist/js/libs/angular/angular'
    ,'file1': 'libs/folder1/file1'
    ,'file2': 'libs/folder2/file2'
    ,'file3': 'libs/folder3/file3'
    ,'async': 'libs/requirejs/2.1.1/async'
    ,'domReady': 'libs/requirejs/2.1.1/domReady'
},

shim: {}});
```

I need to add angular-backbone script to project, trying to add in `path` something like `'angboot': './libs/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls'` but it dosen't work, it's still not presented in the header after page loaded. Also I comment some other files like `file1` or `file2`, but when I reload the page they still in header. I press `ctrl+f5`, clear cache - but result still the same.

What I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you requiring the module anywhere?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm very new with it, just first night of looking through the code. Don't know that to add file t should be declared somewhere. You could provide an answer and I accept it like a correct if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`require.config` only tells RequireJS where to find modules should it need them. It doesn't actually load modules until they're required. Usually, that will either happen as a dependency with `require`:

```
require(['file1', 'file2' /* ... */], function(file1, file2) {
    /* ... */
});
```

…or as a dependency of one of *those* modules (and of those, and so on).